# MIN() not getting the lowest value when there's a decimal in php mysql query

Tags: mysql, sum, min

still not solved

I want to return the total cost of each supplier with the lowest price. the total cost is acquired by getting the sum of the product of item quantity and unit cost.

This is my current code :

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Total) as Total 
  FROM ( SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN bidding.FK_itemId THEN CONCAT(bidding.unitCost, ' - ', 
                supplier.supplierName) END) as 'Cost', 
                supplier.supplierName as 'Name', 
                MIN(bidding.unitCost*item.quantity) as 'Total' 
           FROM bidding 
           LEFT JOIN item ON bidding.FK_itemId = item.PK_itemId 
           LEFT JOIN supplier on bidding.FK_supplierId = supplier.PK_supplierId 
          WHERE bidding.dateAdded = CURDATE() 
          GROUP BY item.itemDesc ORDER BY bidding.FK_itemId
       ) T 
 GROUP by Name;
```

this is what it displays FOR THE TOTAL COST PER SUPPLIER TABLE:
[image: Total Per Supplier]

on the other table that displays and highlights the lowest price:

[image: Total Per Supplier]
as you can see it highlights 9.5 but displays 10 as the lowest price.

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: how does your tables look? Could you add some example data? Perhaps on http://sqlfiddle.com/ so it's easy to play with.

Comment: `CASE WHEN bidding.FK_itemId THEN CONCAT(bidding.unitCost, ' - ', supplier.supplierName) END` produces string value. So when you use MIN over it then it is sorted as string. `'10' < '9.5'`.

Comment: here it is : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb @AndreasWederbrand

Comment: What do you suggest that I do? Thank you! @Akina

Comment: I cannot load your fidle - the page is loaded w/o the data. Please copy it to dbfiddle.uk (and set proper DBMS type/version).

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=83827af058ede3a82b3b95838e8bcdc0 @Akina

Comment: Investigate this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=a77ef74d4944e770540b3674f48f5341 Add desired output for **this** data, add detailed explanations, including the incorrectness.

Comment: I still haven't got the solution. is there anyone who can help me